# Visually Intuitive Measure Theory and Functional Analysis Resources

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, operator-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm looking for resources in measure theory and functional analysis that are visually intuitive. Hoping to find something covering at least as much as Vladimir Kadets' book. I'm looking for something written in the way [these notes](http://euclid.trentu.ca/pivato/Teaching/measure.pdf) are to be specific, but with a more comprehensive coverage.

I hope abstraction hasn't fully gutted the scope for visual aids. Any and all recommendations are much appreciated!